# Finding a closed form for $\sum\limits_{\substack{0\le n\le N\\0\le m\le M}}\left|nM-Nm\right|$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

I am trying to figure out if there is a closed form for the following sum:
$$
\sum_{\substack{0\le n\le N \\ 0\le m\le M}}\left|(N-n)(M-m)-nm\right|=\sum_{\substack{0\le n\le N \\ 0\le m\le M}}\left|nM-Nm\right|.
$$
Clearly, from symmetry, if we remove the absolute values, the sum evaulates to $0$.

Using the symmetry, I tried to evaluate the sum as
$$
2\cdot\sum_{\substack{0\le n\le N \\ 0\le m\le M \\ (N-n)(M-m)\gt nm}}\left((N-n)(M-m)-nm\right).
$$
However, that expression ended up containing sums of floor functions, for which I did not know a closed form.

Is there another way to obtain a closed form for the above sum?

---

**Edit**: If no closed form can be provided an efficient algorithm to compute the above sum given $N,M$ would also be good.

---

**Edit 2**: Since the time I have placed the bounty, I was able to find a closed form for the sum:

> $$\frac{1}{6}\left[MN(2 M N + 3 (M + N + 1)) + M^2 + N^2-\gcd(M,N)^2\right].$$

So now I change the question to a challange: derive the above form from the sum. The prettiest derivation (if there are any) will get the bounty.

Comment: Your first identity looks wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Simply replace $N-n$ with $n$ in the sum.

Comment: you are right, thanks.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I don't know about the downvotes, but it is not the purpose of this site to play challenges. We are helping people that face difficulties.

Comment: First off, at the time of posting the question (and the bounty), I did not have a solution and was indeed seeking help. Second, even if I were to post it initially as a challenge, why can't the site do both?

Comment: This is the site's policy, that's all. There are other SO places for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, here's my own derivation:

First, given $d:=\gcd(M,N)$, $\,N':= N/d$, we have the following identity:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N}f\left(\left\{n\frac{M}{N}\right\}\right)
=f\left(0\right)+d\sum_{n=0}^{N'-1}f\left(\frac{n}{N'}\right)
$$
Removing the absolute value will give a sum that equals $0$. Hence, the positive part of the sum is equal to the negative part. Thus:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{m=0}^M\left|nM-Nm\right| &= 2\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{m=0}^{\left\lfloor n\frac{M}{N}\right\rfloor}\left(nM-Nm\right) \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N\left(2\left(\left\lfloor n\frac{M}{N}\right\rfloor+1\right)nM-N\left(\left\lfloor n\frac{M}{N}\right\rfloor^2+\left\lfloor n\frac{M}{N}\right\rfloor\right)\right) \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N\left(\left\lfloor n\frac{M}{N}\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(2nM-N\left\lfloor n\frac{M}{N}\right\rfloor\right) \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N\left(n\frac{M}{N}-\left\{ n\frac{M}{N}\right\}+1\right)\left(nM+N\left\{ n\frac{M}{N}\right\}\right) \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N\left(n^2\frac{M^2}{N}+nM-N\left\{ n\frac{M}{N}\right\}^2+N\left\{ n\frac{M}{N}\right\}\right) \\
&=\small{\frac{1}{6}\left((N+1)(2N+1)M^2+3N(N+1)M-Nd\frac{(N'-1)(2N'-1)}{N'}+3Nd(N'-1)\right)} \\
&=\small{\frac{1}{6}\left((N+1)(2N+1)M^2+3N(N+1)M-(N-d)(2N-d)+3N(N-d)\right)} \\
&=\frac{1}{6}\left(MN(2MN + 3(M+N+1)) +M^2 +N^2-d^2\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$Suppose $M, N > 0$ and $d = (M, N)$, $M = md$, $N = nd$.\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N}} |kN - jM| &= \sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1}} |kN - jM| + \sum_{k = 0}^{M - 1} (NM - kN) + \sum_{j = 0}^{N - 1} (MN - jM)\\
&= \sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1}} |kN - jM| + \frac{1}{2} NM(M + 1) + \frac{1}{2} MN(N + 1). \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Note that$$
\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1}} (kN - jM) = \frac{1}{2} NM(M - 1) - \frac{1}{2} MN(N - 1),
$$
then\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1}} |kN - jM| &= \sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1\\kN\geqslant jM}} (kN - jM) - \sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1\\kN<jM}} (kN - jM)\\
&= 2\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1\\kN\geqslant jM}} (kN - jM) - \sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1}} (kN - jM)
\end{align*}
which implies$$
(1) = 2\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1\\kN\geqslant jM}} (kN - jM) + MN(N + 1). \tag{2}
$$

Now for each $0 \leqslant k \leqslant M - 1$, define $$r_k = kn - m\left[ \dfrac{kn}{m} \right],$$ i.e. $r_k$ is the remainder of $kn$ modulo $m$.
\begin{align*}
&\peq \sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1\\kN\geqslant jM}} (kN - jM) = \sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant dm-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant dn-1\\kdn\geqslant jdm}} (kdn - jdm) = d \sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant dm-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant dn-1\\kn\geqslant jm}} (kn - jm)\\
&= d\sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} \sum_{j = 0}^{\left[ \frac{kn}{m} \right]} (kn - jm) = d\sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} \left( kn \left( \left[ \frac{kn}{m} \right] + 1 \right) - m·\frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{kn}{m} \right] \left( \left[ \frac{kn}{m} \right] + 1 \right) \right)\\
&= d\sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} \left( kn - \frac{m}{2} \left[ \frac{kn}{m} \right] \right) \left( \left[ \frac{kn}{m} \right] + 1 \right) = d\sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} \left( kn - \frac{m}{2}·\frac{kn - r_k}{m} \right) \left( \frac{kn - r_k}{m} + 1 \right)\\
&= d\sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} \left( \frac{1}{2} kn + \frac{1}{2} r_k \right) \left( \frac{kn}{m} + 1 - \frac{r_k}{m} \right) = \frac{d}{2m} \sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} (kn(kn + m) + m r_k - r_k^2). \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Note that $(m, n) = 1$ implies for each $0 \leqslant s \leqslant d - 1$,$$\{kn \mid sm \leqslant k \leqslant (s + 1)m - 1\}$$ is a complete residue system modulo $m$, therefore$$
\{r_{sm}, \cdots, r_{(s + 1)m - 1}\} = \{ 0, \cdots, m - 1\}.
$$
Thus$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} r_k = \sum_{s = 0}^{d - 1} \sum_{k = sm}^{(s + 1)m - 1} r_k = \sum_{s = 0}^{d - 1} \sum_{k = 0}^{m - 1} k = \frac{1}{2} m(m - 1)·d,\\
\sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} r_k^2 = \sum_{s = 0}^{d - 1} \sum_{k = 0}^{m - 1} r_k^2 = \sum_{s = 0}^{d - 1} \sum_{k = 0}^{m - 1} k^2 = \frac{1}{6} (2m - 1)(m - 1)m·d,
$$
then\begin{align*}
(3) &= \frac{d}{2m} \sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} kn(kn + m) + \frac{d}{2} \sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} r_k - \frac{d}{2m} \sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} r_k^2\\
&= \frac{dn^2}{2m} \sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} k^2 + \frac{1}{2} dn \sum_{k = 0}^{dm - 1} k + \frac{d}{2} × \frac{1}{2} m(m - 1)·d - \frac{d}{2m} × \frac{1}{6} (2m - 1)(m - 1)m·d\\
&= \frac{dn^2}{2m} × \frac{1}{6} (2dm - 1)(dm - 1)dm + \frac{1}{2} dn × \frac{1}{2} (dm - 1)dm\\
&\peq + \frac{d}{2} × \frac{1}{2} m(m - 1)·d - \frac{d}{2m} × \frac{1}{6} (2m - 1)(m - 1)m·d\\
&= \frac{1}{6} d^4 m^2 n^2 + \frac{1}{4} d^3 mn(m - n) + \frac{1}{12} d^2 (m^2 + n^2 - 3mn) - \frac{1}{12} d^2.
\end{align*}

Combining with (2),\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N}} |kN - jM| &= 2\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant M-1\\0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1\\kN\geqslant jM}} (kN - jM) + MN(N + 1)\\
&= 2\left( \frac{1}{6} d^4 m^2 n^2 + \frac{1}{4} d^3 mn(m - n) + \frac{1}{12} d^2 (m^2 + n^2 - 3mn) - \frac{1}{12} d^2 \right)\\
&\peq + d^2 mn(dn + 1)\\
&= \frac{1}{3} d^4 m^2 n^2 + \frac{1}{2} d^3 mn(m + n) + \frac{1}{6} d^2 (m^2 + n^2 + 3mn) - \frac{1}{6} d^2\\
&=\frac{1}{6} \left( MN(2MN + 3(M + N + 1)) + M^2 + N^2-(M,N)^2\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: I think the sums could be significatly simplified (and you could probably have just one case) if you use the following identities:
$$
\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor = x - \left\{x\right\}
$$
(where $\{\cdot\}$ is the fractional part) and
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}{f\left(\left\{\frac{nM}{N}\right\}\right)}=d\sum_{n=0}^{N'-1}{f\left(\frac{n}{N'}\right)}
$$
(where $d := \gcd(M,N)$ and $N' := \frac{N}{d}$).

Comment: In our sum, we'll have $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=x^2$, so if we sum up to $N$ (instead of $N-1$), we'll get the same value.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The problem is governed by the solutions of $Mn=Nm$, the main diagonal of the rectangle. WLOG $M\ge N$ and let us assume for now that $M,N$ are relative primes, so that equality only occurs at the corners.

By symmetry, we just look below the diagonal and for a given $m$,

$$0\le n\le\left\lfloor{\frac{Nm}M}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor{Qm}\right\rfloor.$$

Then,

$$S:=\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\left\lfloor{Qm}\right\rfloor}(Nm-Mn)=M\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\left\lfloor{Qm}\right\rfloor}(Qm-n)\\
=M\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\left(Qm-\frac12\left\lfloor{Qm}\right\rfloor\right)\left(\left\lfloor{Qm}\right\rfloor+1\right)\\
=\frac M2\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\left(Qm+\{Qm\}\right)\left(Qm-\{Qm\}+1\right)\\
=\frac M2\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\left((Qm)^2+Qm-\{Qm\}^2+\{Qm\}\right).$$

As in the sums of fractional parts, all fractions from $0/M$ to $(M-1)/M$ appear (in disorder),

$$12S=6M\left(Q^2\frac{(M-1)M(2M-1)}6+Q\frac{(M-1)M}2-\frac{(M-1)M(2M-1)}{6M^2}+\frac{(M-1)M}{2M}\right)\\
=2M^2N^2+M^2-3MN^2-3MN+N^2+3NM^2-1.$$

To this, we need to add the omitted term ($m=M$), which is found to be

$$T:=\sum_{n=0}^{N}(NM-Mn)=\frac{MN(N+1)}2,$$

and finally

$$2(S+T)=\frac{2M^2N^2+M^2+9MN^2+9MN+N^2+3NM^2-1}6.$$

Now if $M,N$ are not relative primes, one may split the summation in $G=\gcd(M,N)$ subsums of $\dfrac MG$ terms and a final $M^{th}$ term. This amounts to replacing the final $-1$ by $-G^2$.

Comment: Calculation errors are not excluded. Not at all ;-)

Comment: Note that in the final general expression $G$ should be raised to the second power.

Comment: @SomeStrangeUser: this is the first calculation error discovered :-)

Comment: A couple of additional notes:
$ \\ $
(1) It may be simpler to sum $m$ up to $M$ right from the start. This saves us the extra term computation, and doesn't affect the fractional parts of the sum (since $\{QM\}=0$).
$ \\ $
(2) Removing the assumption that $M,N$ are relatively prime does not change most of the original computation. In fact, all it does is change the final step, when computing the sums of the fractional parts, where the closed forms have $M'=M/d$ instead of $M$ and are multiplied by $d=\gcd(M,N)$. After reordring, the $M'$ terms neatly disappear.

Comment: @SomeStrangeUser: so in the end it is not so difficult. A critical point in the resolution is the fact that there is no term in $Qm\{Qm\}$ in the expression of $S$, which I wouldn't know how to handle.

Answer (score -1):

Partial solution:

We can break the expression into four parts $E_1 + E_2 + E_3 + E_4$

where $$E_1 = \sum_{\substack{0\le n\le N/2 \\ 0\le m\le M/2}}(MN -mN-nM) = $$
$$E_2 = \sum_{\substack{0\le n\le N/2 \\ M/2\le m\le M}}|MN -mN-nM|$$
$$E_3 = \sum_{\substack{N/2\le n\le N \\ 0\le m\le M/2}}|MN -mN-nM|$$
$$E_4 = \sum_{\substack{N/2\le n\le N \\ M/2\le m\le M}}(mN + nM - MN) = \sum_{\substack{0\le n\le N/2 \\ 0\le m\le M/2}}(mN + nM)$$

$E_1 + E_4 = M^2N^2/4$

Both $E_2$ and $E_3$ can be rewritten as

$$ E_2 = E_3 = \sum_{\substack{0\le n\le N/2 \\ 0\le m\le M/2}}|MN/2 -mN-nM|$$

so $$E_2 + E_3 = \sum_{\substack{0\le n\le N/2 \\ 0\le m\le M/2}}|MN -2mN-2nM|$$

So $$LHS = M^2N^2/4 + \sum_{\substack{0\le n\le N/2 \\ 0\le m\le M/2}}|MN -2mN-2nM|$$ 
and may be we can recursively move forward?

Comment: Downvoter, would you please explain yourself? Thanks